# Is Epoxy Adhesive Glue (specifically Araldite) a good insulator

Tags: insulation

I snapped off a piece of insulating plastic (on a car stater motor) and want to glue it back on with some Epoxy Adhesive Glue (specifically Aradlite) glue, could someone tell me if this is a good electrical insulator or not?

http://www.screwfix.com/p/araldite-2-part-epoxy-adhesive-tubes-opaque-2-x-15ml/2457h

http://www.my-sds.co.uk/Admin/ViewDocument.aspx?ID=9c3084d6-ab98-4f61-bc32-8ab675547ecb&primaryReportId=0

Comment: Epoxy is a good insulator. That does not mean your plan is a good one. But it answers your electrical engineering question. For your information, there are some formulations of epoxy which are heavily doped with silver. There are so many silver particles that the cured product is actually conductive. But araldite is not doped with silver, so you don't need to worry.

Comment: Your job is low volts so dont worry too much .I think it will be interesting to get some real answers when there are high voltages and high frequencies. +1

Comment: Yoy may be (sadly) surprised how poorly ARaldite works in your application. It can be utterly superb but needs to have immaculately clean surfaces and to be compatible with the materials used. You MAY need to add some form of mechanical join for strength. The Araldite then adds retention force and fine positioning. A photo would help.

Comment: @Autistic, although it's low voltage, it's also very high AMPS. A poorly attached epoxy "fix" could result in a short and a fire. A more mechanically sound fix is probably warranted.

Comment: You may add some mica powder with Araldite as it will improve its insulating property and will also help in setting eatlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, epoxy is generally a good insulator.

There are some types that are formulated to either conduct or at least bleed off static charge.  That has to be done deliberately with certain additives.  If so, this will be prominently featured on the label.

For example, I vaguely remember that 3M makes a "conductive" epoxy that has a lot of carbon in it, which also makes it look black.

Comment: I have mixed graphite powder in epoxy before. Even though it seemed like a lot of graphite powder to me, and changed the consistency of the epoxy, it was still electrically non-conductive. I suspect the conductive epoxies are mixed with a very high addition of the conductive element. This is just a little extra info for anyone who may be reading.